# How to change the default background color white to something else in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a web application where I have set my default color to navy blue using css. But when i added the twitter bootstrap css's in my page I did not find my navy blue color instead I found the white background color provided by twitter bootstrap.

My query is that what portion of css should I change in bootstrap to change my page's background.

Comment: You mean the body color?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a pretty simple task if you have your own stylesheet working in tandem with the bootstrap stylesheet.

Comment: I think it is strange that none of the answers shows how to change the background color in the HTML code, using Bootstrap classes, such as "bg-secondary". Bootstrap should eliminate the need for custom CSS code.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can overwrite Bootstraps default CSS by adding your own rules.

```
<style type="text/css">
   body { background: navy !important; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
</style>
```

Answer (score 30):

Bootstrap 4 provides standard methods for this, fully described here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming

Eg. you can override defaults simply by setting variables in the SASS file, where you import bootstrap. An example from the docs (which also answers the question):

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: This is the right answer. It's more likely to interact well with updated releases of bootstrap, and allows for additional changes that might flow on from changing the body background to be applied by the bootstrap SCSS.

Answer (score 18):

You have to override the bootstrap default by being a bit more specific. Try this for a black background:

```
html body {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);

}
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the hex color code didn't work but the rgba format did in my case for the exact same CSS?

Comment: @Annjawn do you know why? did you ever figure out why?

Comment: The hex colour should work just fine, as long as the selector is more specific e.g. "html body {background-color:#000;}" rather than "body {background-color:#000;}". 
Although it's also possible the "background-color" attribute could override the bootstrap default. I'd be very surprised if the colour format would make a difference.

Answer (score 12):

I would not recommend changing the actual bootstrap CSS files. If you do not want to use Jako's first solution you can create a custom bootstrap style sheet with one of the available  Bootstrap theme generator ([Bootstrap theme generators](http://www.webdesignforbeginners.info/bootstrap-theme-generators/)). That way you can use 1 style sheet with all of the default Bootstrap CSS with just the one change to it that you want. With a Bootstrap theme generator you do not need to write any CSS. You only need to set the hex values for the color you want for the body (Scaffolding; bodyBackground).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply add this line into your bootstrap_and_overides.css.less file

```
body { background: #000000 !important;}
```

that's it

Answer (score 6):

I'm using CDN bootstrap, and the solution that I found was:
First, include the bootstrap's CDN, then in the next line, you include the file `.css` where you are editing the default styles of bootstrap.

```
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Your styles -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/my_bootsrap_editions.css'>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add your own .css file & put in it:

```
body{
    background: navy;
}
```

**Important:**  While including css files in html, first include the cdn bootstrap css, then only include your own .css file. This way stylings in your own css file overrides the default behaviour from bootstrap css.

Answer (score 2):

**The colors changed due to the order of CSS files.**

Place the custom CSS under the bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended to overwrite bootstrap file, just in your local style.css use

body{background: your color **!important**;

here **!important** declaration overwrite bootstrap value.

Answer (score 0):

how to change background color in html & css with class

example:

on html you write

```
<div class="pad_menu">
</div>
```

on css

```
.pad_menu {
   padding: 100px;
   background-color: #A9FFCB;
}
```

so your background will be change to Magic Mint, if you want to know the code of the color, i suggest you visit https://coolors.co. Hope this useful :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question.