# How to change twitter bootstrap background color

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I already tried the custom function from the website, but keeps give me error, and tried the BASIC method too:

```
body {background-color:red;}
```

so, does anyone know?

Comment: I try to build the custom css but it says: Ruh roh! Could not save gist file, configuration not saved.

Comment: which version of bootstrap? are you talking about one of the examples? please point to some code, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Download all of the bootstrap files and somewhere inside the .css file add:

```
body {
   background:red !important;
}
```

Comment: it worked! thanks! .. Also, is this method works in all browsers?

Comment: Yes. when adding !important to the end of a css style it replaces every other style of the same class/element.

Comment: Although this technically works, it should only be used if you cannot use the default bg-classes as Oceinic states in his answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30920054/5476434  - if you override this in your css, it may make it difficult to maintain your code in the future as you've got several sources where background colors come from which makes it hard to understand

Comment: @TimSchoch `bg-danger` does not produce a `red` background, but a red-ish background. However, I agree, that this is a dirty solution. If someone was to change it properly would be either using the source SASS files or edit the actual distributed `bootstrap.css` file and change the background color there.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to change background color in Bootstrap 3 is to use `bg-*` classes. For red color there is `bg-danger`. Also available `bg-primary, bg-success, bg-info and bg-warning`.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds

Comment: This answer should appear first. Try the bootstrap way first (using `bg-*` classes) and resort to a custom class only if the semantic styling options are not enough.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend changing the actual bootstrap CSS files. You can create a custom bootstrap style sheet with one of the available [Bootstrap theme generator](http://www.webdesignforbeginners.info/bootstrap-theme-generators/) (Bootstrap theme generators). That way you can use 1 style sheet with all of the default Bootstrap CSS with just the one change to it that you want. With a Bootstrap theme generator you do not need to write any CSS. You only need to set the hex values for the color you want for the body (Scaffolding; bodyBackground).

SOURCE: [How to change the default background color white to something else in twitter boostrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768891/how-to-change-the-default-background-color-white-to-something-else-in-twitter-bo)

Comment: theme generator website no longer available =(

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend using Sass with [Bootstrap-Sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) not just for making any customisations to the core Bootstrap framework but also to ensure your CSS is as DRY as possible. Then you can do something like

```
$red: #f00;

$body-bg: $red;
```

before you import your core Bootstrap CSS, and you will be good to go. Note that Sass allows you to reuse the variable ($red) you just declared anywhere else you may like in your app.

The benefits of using a CSS preprocessor like Sass or LESS don't end here. Bootstrap is based on a proportionate system of font sizes, so you can also do something like

```
$font-size-base: 16px;
```

and that will accordingly change the font sizes of all elements (p, h1..h6 etc) across the board. You may also, for example, write

```
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Gill Sans';
```

and that will replace Helvetica as the default sans-serif font for all elements.

Look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) for all the customisations you can make to your code whenever you wish and not just while downloading Bootstrap if you use Sass.

Answer (score 0):

In html change  to 
In CSS change "body {}" to ".body {}"
This is because a CLASS is more specific than a tag, and so it will take the rule over the main bootsrap.css which only classifies as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have a boilerplate I've created that I use to create bootstrap themes, that will generate docs using the theme you've created. I've implemented this at companies that use it across multiple web teams in order to get a branded result while just using basic bootstrap components.

Check it out here: https://github.com/patrickleet/bootstrap-override-boilerplate

There are instructions in the README

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 3.3 Add the following BG Style.

```
body{
background-color: gray !important;
}
```

Source : from Bootstrap 3.3 Guide.