# How to change the color of the background the bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the background color of the bootstrap theme.
This background:
[background1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gHhh.png)

and this background:
[background2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEpQI.png)

I want to change the color to blue for green. I was checking out the file sb-admin-2.min, but the maximios that I can do it, was change the collor of the buttons for example. Someone can help me?
Follow the link for see the file [sb-admin-2.min](http://americaribeiro.atwebpages.com/escolar/css/sb-admin-2.min.css)
If you want to see my project, you can enter in this website: http://americaribeiro.atwebpages.com/escolar/ and use the email: romeu@romeu.com and password: 123

Comment: welcome! please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I answered but possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768891/how-to-change-the-default-background-color-white-to-something-else-in-twitter-bo/28222348

Comment: change `bg-gradient-info` to `bg-success`   in sidebar element

Comment: Use your own class, do not overwite the global style. Just add on your class name and style that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]To change the background of the first image, change the background property of body element in index.php

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: red; // here
 }
```

To change the background of the second image,in sb-admin-2.css

```
.bg-gradient-info {
  background-color: red; //here, you can override this class
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply overwrite bootstrap styling with your own style.

```css
.my-class {
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="some-bootstrap-class my-class"> Hello </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector
`body{ background: #36b9cc !important; }` for using your green color.